# How do I get multiple inputs from the user with Python?

Tags: python

I would like to create a program that will input the enter size to the user and then enter type of individual triangle to select whether it is empty or no_empty, output 1 to 4 if empty and output 5 to 8 if no_empty.

My code is now this.

```
tri = int(input("enter size : "))
empthy = input("type of rectangle triangle : " )
choice = int(input("Choose the triangle you want to draw.\n1. triangle1 \n2. triangle2 \n3. triangle3 \n4. triangle4 \n5. triangle5 \n6. triangle6 \n7. triangle7 \n8. triangle8\n== >"))
print_triangle(tri, empthy, choice)
```

But an example of the code that I want to make,

enter size: 10

type of rectangle triangle : empthy

Choose the triangle you want to draw
n1. triangle1 \n2. triangle2 \n3. triangle3 \n4. triangle4

or

enter size: 10

type of rectangle triangle : no_empthy

Choose the triangle you want to draw
n5. triangle5 \n6. triangle6 \n7. triangle7 \n8. triangle8

My problem is
If you select no_empty in ("type of vertical triangle"), it will output everything from 1 to 8.

Comment: And what issues did you encounter?

Comment: If you select no_empty in ("type of vertical triangle"), it will output everything from 1 to 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `if - else` to decide between the triangles you want to show to user such as:

```
tri = int(input("enter size : "))
empty = input("type of rectangle triangle : " )
if empty=="empty":
   choice = int(input("Choose the triangle you want to draw.\n1. triangle1 \n2. triangle2 \n3. triangle3 \n4. triangle4\n== >"))
elif empty=="no_empty":
   choice = int(input("Choose the triangle you want to draw.\n5. triangle5 \n6. triangle6 \n7. triangle7 \n8. triangle8\n== >"))
print_triangle(tri, empty, choice)
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow brother!!

```
triangle_size = int(input("Enter size : "))
filling = input("Do you want empty triangle or no_empty triangle: ")
if(filling=="empty"):
   choice = int(input("Choose the triangle you want to draw.\n1. triangle1 \n2. triangle2 \n3. triangle3 \n4. triangle4\n== >"))
elif(filling=="no_empty"):
   choice = int(input("Choose the triangle you want to draw.\n5. triangle5 \n6. triangle6 \n7. triangle7 \n8. triangle8\n== >"))
print_triangle(triangle_size, empty, choice)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell without seeing the code of `print_triangle` function why does it output everything from 1 to 8, but if you need to validate your input you could do something like this.

1) Declare a function that determines if the input is valid. E.g. if we want to check if the input is right type of integer, we do:

```
def validate_integer_input(s):
    return int(s)

def validate_exactly_2_int_input(s):
    parts = s.split()
    if len(parts) != 2:
        raise ValueError
    return list(map(int, parts))
```

Validator returns value or raises ValueError if something is not good with the data.

2) Then you write modified input function as follows:

```
def validated_input(validator):
    while True:
        try:
            return validator(input())
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

This function will keep trying receiving the input from user until correct data is entered.

3) Use it:

```
a = validated_input(validate_integer_input)
pairs = validated_input(validate_exactly_2_int_input)
```